# couldn't ping router, although it offered an IP-address

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, laptop, broadcom

I've installed Linux Mint 16 on my HP envy 6. It activated automatically the proprietary driver, which recognized the WiFi interface and called it eth1.
I could connect to my router, I get the IP address 192.168.0.100, but I'm still not able to get an internet connection, or ping the routers IP.

#### Questions

- What could be a solution for that problem?
- Is the power management of the interface a problem?

Output of `traceroute` and `ip route show`:

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8  
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
1 * * *  
2 * * *  
3 * * *  
4 * * *  
5 * * *  
6 * 72.14.238.153 (72.14.238.153) 399.087 ms *  
7 * * *  
8 * * *  
9 * * *  
10 * * *  
11 * * * 12 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 261.041 ms 260.956 ms * 

$ ip route show  
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static  
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.112 metric 1  
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100 metric 9
```

Comment: Yes, there probably is a solution. Can you ping outside IP addresses like `173.194.113.128`? If you can, you "just" have problems with resolving names. If you can't ping, your routers is not doing its job forwarding.

Comment: No, I can't ping such an adress, but I don't think that the router is the problem, because my mobile phone connects perfectly to the internet. I even could not ping my router.

Comment: so what does: connect to your access point mean, is that not your router? Can you ping your AP?

Comment: my acces point is my router

Comment: If you look at the AP/Router with your mobilephone can you see it handed out an IP address to your laptop?

Comment: yes,it's registered at the router, but it still couldn't ping it.

Comment: `traceroute 8.8.8.8` gives you what output ?

Comment: Please provide the output of: ip route show

Comment: You better update your question with info and leave a short comment using `@username` to notify the person requesting the info.

Comment: @jonadev95 use the [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/115050/edit) link under the answer to add the information.

Comment: @Kiwy
I've added the traceroute output to the question

Comment: @KeiranHolloway
I've added the ip route show output to the question

Comment: `traceroute` depends on the hosts en route sending back TIME TO LIVE EXCEEDED ICMP messages when packets time out. If your router doesn't send them, it won't show up. Ditto for `ping(1)`, it sends an ICMP ECHO REQUEST, that the target should answer with ECHO REPLY. If the target doesn't answer, you won't see it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have two interfaces with IPs from the same network. Even though they have different metric I would try disabling one interface and checking with the other. So I would `ifconfig eth1 down`, check routes again, if they are ok try to ping first your router 192.168.0.1 if it works try to ping 8.8.8.8. If you can ping the router but not the outside IP the problem could be in the router, so you will need to check its configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and it was caused by MAC & IP binding settings on the router. My router showed a different MAC address for my Linux Mint machine than ifconfig claimed the eth0 connection should have. I released the bindings in the router settings and rebooted the router and the correct MAC address showed up. My router is a TP-Link TL-MR3420.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can see.

1. Your DNS resolution is not working properly.  Try edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add in some nameservers. 8.8.8.8 should be sufficient to get this working.

   ```
   echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   Would do this, but you should check that there isn't other incorrect resolvers in there..  then well, you're going to still have problems.  That above is an ugly hack, but it might work.
2. You're seeing slow ping responses and packet loss.. there's something not too healthy with your internet connection.   Speak with your ISP.

Comment: I've formatted it in the question and I've tried to add the line to resolv.conf, but it doesn't solve the problem.
My guess would be it's a wifi problem, because the ethernet connection on this laptop works normally.

Comment: You could compare the output of the traceroute on the laptop, but you're seeing a huge amount of packet loss and lots of latency. DNS resolution should be working now (albeit slowly) assuming that /etc/resolv.conf is right.

Comment: I'm not shure if I'm doing it right, but the added line in resolv.conf gets overwritten when I reboot the laptop

Comment: Probably, it is likely to be using DHCP, so getting the DNS information from the router.. I cannot comment on the health of the DNS resolv/cache of the router which most likely is being used.  but I know that google's 8.8.8.8 is working fine.

Comment: but could the dns resolv of the router be broken if I could connect my mobile phone via the router to the internet without a problem?